# What causes this Pinterest-style column layout to not work on Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox, cross-browser, multiple-columns

http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-only-pinterest-style-columns-layout

I have tried this code snippet on Explorer, Chrome and Safari with success, but the layout is only one column wide in Firefox version 39.0. This means that something about the column layout CSS is not understood.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `-moz-column-fill: auto` isn't acting the same in Firefox. It appears to work in both Chrome and Firefox if you use `-moz-column-fill: balance` instead. It should appear the same since the width is constant.

The [MDN page on column-fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-fill) has more information.